# AVPlayer freezes on load

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

My app seems to freeze the UI (guess it's running on the main thread) when it's loading. I followed the advice of other S.O answers and used `loadValuesAsynchronously`, but that didn't really seem to help. Any ideas why it's happening?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    let asset = AVURLAsset(url: self.URL, options: nil)
    asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["duration"], completionHandler: { () -> Void in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(asset)
        }
    })
}

//above completion calls: 
fileprivate func validateAsset(_ asset : AVURLAsset) -> Bool {
    var e: NSError?
    asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &e)
    if let error = e {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

I made a breakpoint when the UI freezes up and it points to this line in particular:

```
asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "duration", error: &e)
```

Comment: what is `completion` in your code? and why do you run the asset creation on background thread?

Comment: sorry about the confusion, I made an edit. the top functions completion calls the below `validateAsset` function

Comment: again, include the code of the completion as well.. there might be some side effect cause by the code you do not show here. and again, explain **why** you create the asset on the background thread.. also, if you claim that you followed some SO advices, you should include links to those as well..

Comment: Seems nowhere cause UI freeze. Can you add more code to track?

Comment: Why is the `&` in that line of code?

Comment: I faced the same issue, @ChrisJones Found any solution?

Comment: I was using some framework (i forget the name) to make this happen. Anyway, the solution was to run the load on the background thread. I htink it was called Jukebox or something

Comment: @ChrisJones Did you manage to fix it ? if yes how ?